# Method showing up in getDeclaredMethods(), but can't be found with getDeclaredMethod(), why?

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to use the snippet:

```
GenericModel.class.getDeclaredMethod("findById");
```

to get a Method called "findById". I know the method exists, because when I call:

```
GenericModel.class.getDeclaredMethods();
```

the method is listed in the array returned.

However, when using the first snippet, I am getting a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException? Why?

Comment: I even tried copying and pasting the name of the method, to avoid me making spelling mistakes, but to no avail.

Comment: If I call GenericModel.class.getDeclaredMethod("findAll") or any other method on the class, it is successful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably `findById` actually takes parameters.  But you are searching for a method by that name that takes none.  Most likely what you want is:

```
GenericModel.class.getDeclaredMethod("findById", new Class[] { int.class });
```

This will match a method that has a signature like this:

```
Object findById(int id) { ... }
```

Comment: Method method = field.getType().getDeclaredMethod("findById", new Class[]{ Object.class });

Answer (score 2):

[`getDeclaredMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) receives parameter types as well, and you didn't give it any, and in the case of `findViewById`, it's a method that receives an `int` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the name, `findById` takes arguments. However, you're not passing any in. You need to specify the findById's arguments as additional parameters for the call to `getDeclaredMethod` so it knows which method to give you - there could be ten different findById's.

Answer (score 0):

In my project there are several `ClassLoaders`.

The classes of the method arguments are the same, but the `ClassLoaders` (or instances of ClassLoaders) that load those classes are different.

For example, `ClassA` has method `methodA` with argument `argumentA` typed `com.example.A`, loaded by class loader `ClassLoaderA`.

However, in your java CLASSPATH, you have `com.example.A`, loaded by class loader **`ClassLoaderB`**. When you call `ClassA.class.getDeclaredMethod("methodA", new Class[] { A.class });`, it will still fail to find the method. **Because `com.example.A` loaded by `ClassLoaderA` is not the same as `com.example.A` loaded by `ClassLoaderB`.**

The parent-delegation model / singleton pattern for custom class loaders can be used to solve the problem.

I know it is not related to this case, but it is one possible reason why *Method showing up in getDeclaredMethods(), but can't be found with getDeclaredMethod()*.